# Handling Mixed-Model with varying repeated measure time spacing in R

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, longitudinal

We have a sample using a 1 group, repeated measures design. Participants may receive measures at the same or different time points. I want to look at whether there has been a decline in their scores from the initial measurement.

I'm confused about how to specify the model when participants may have different measurement intervals. I've calculated the difference in days from the initial measurement, as well as created a month-group column to help align time periods that match.

As far as I can understand, the ID is fixed, and my month-group is random. Is this the right formula? Should I be using base_distance instead or calculate the days between measurements?

lmer(SEVERITY ~ MONTH_GROUP + (1|ID), REML = F, df)

[image]

Sample (de-identified) code is below.

```
install.packages("lme4")
library(lme4)
df <-structure(list(DATE = structure(c(17417, 17501, 17655, 17312, 
17375, 17431, 17487, 17550, 17298, 17384, 17438, 17483, 17536, 
17657), class = "Date"), ID = c("112", "112", "112", "000", "000", 
"000", "000", "000", "100", "100", "100", "100", "100", "100"
), VALUE = c(4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), BASE_DISTANCE = c(0L, 
84L, 238L, 0L, 63L, 119L, 175L, 238L, 0L, 86L, 140L, 185L, 238L, 
359L), MONTH_GROUP = c(0, 2, 7, 0, 2, 3, 5, 7, 0, 2, 4, 6, 7, 
11)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-14L), groups = structure(list(ID = c("000", "100", "112"), .rows = structure(list(
    4:8, 9:14, 1:3), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .drop = TRUE))


fm1 <- lmer(SEVERITY ~ MONTH_GROUP + (1|ID), REML = F, df)
summary(fm1)
```

Comment: You say "the ID is fixed, and my month-group is random", but it's the other way around in your code (which seems the right way around to me). Since you are interested in the slope of `month_group`, I would add a random slope to your model: `severity ~ month_group + (1 + monthgroup | ID)`.

Comment: @Axeman, post as answer?